# Trigger double press when key held

Tags: triggers, command, autohotkey

*I am new to stackoverflow and apologize in advance if what I am trying to explain is unclear*.

---

I have tried multiple ways to make this work but have had no success so far.

I am trying to achieve the following:

When `F3` is held and `left` arrow is pressed, `left` arrow will be pressed twice with no pause (0sec).

When `F3` is held and `right` arrow is pressed, `right` arrow will be pressed twice with no pause (0sec).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You've gotten a down vote, this is likely because you are not showing any of the code you have tried. While I don't mind this, others do. I'd be willing to bet if you edited your post with the code you tried, that down vote would go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative to Blauhirn's

```
F3::
    While (GetKeyState("F3", "P")) {
        If (GetKeyState("Left", "P"))
            SendInput, {Left}
        If (GetKeyState("Right", "P"))
            SendInput, {Right}
    }
Return
```

Alternatively you don't need to Loop to send multiples of of the same key.

You can simply use `SendInput, {Left 4}` the number represents the number of times that key will be sent.

Edit:

Oops, I didn't address the issue of delay between key presses. So I changed `Send` to `SendInput` as that has no delay between key presses.

Answer (score 0):

```
~F3 & ~left::
    send {left}
return
```

does this work?

This means, that as soon as <kbd>f3</kbd> and <kbd>left</kbd> is pressed together, <kbd>left</kbd> will be sent a second time. If you want to repeat the `send {left}`command, use it like

```
loop, 4 ; 4 times
{
    send {left}
}
```